# How to make an EditText textfield available for multiple xml layouts in Android App?

Tags: android-layout, android-edittext

I want to place an EditText in my android application that will remain same for three layouts or more specifically the EditText field will available for three activities having different other properties(like different TextView, Button etc.) Can anyone tell me how can I do this?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PhoneEditText extends EditText {

    public PhoneEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public PhoneEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public PhoneEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
            // set your input filter here
    }
}


n XML layout you would simply use the full path to your custom class instead EditText:

<my.package.path.to.PhoneEditText android:id="@+id/one"
   attribute="value (all EditText attributes will work as they did before)" />

<my.package.path.to.PhoneEditText android:id="@+id/two"
   attribute="value (all EditText attributes will work as they did before)" />


that's it....
```